# how to convert 2d list to 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D list something like

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

and I want to convert it to a 2d numpy array. Can we do it without allocating memory like

```
numpy.zeros((3,3))
```

and then storing values to it?

Comment: @Donkopotamus, It was a mistake by me... I was giving a sequence... I was doing the same but getting the error. After I got the same code from here I checked where the prob is... So it helps... offcourse I do check the documentation before posting here... Thanks for the friendly reminder.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Just pass the list to `np.array`:

```
a = np.array(a)
```

You can also take this opportunity to set the `dtype` if the default is not what you desire.

```
a = np.array(a, dtype=...)
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work.  you'll get a numpy array of python lists.

Comment: @user1816847 That only happens when the 'sub' lists differ in length (eg: [[1,2], [1,2], [1,2,3]]. It does work with the example given in the question.

Comment: If the sub-arrays do not have the same length, this solution will only give you a numpy array of lists (i.e. the inner lists won't be converted to numpy arrays).
Which totally makes sense as you cannot have a 2D array (matrix) with variable 2nd dimension.

Comment: Thank you from September 2017 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).   This is what I needed.  Much simpler than anticipated.

Comment: Thanks for the important answer, @compie

Comment: Use np.concatenate(YOUR_LIST) if you have a list of an array and you want a single array.

Answer (score 3):

`np.array()` is even more powerful than what unutbu said above.
You also could use it to convert a list of np arrays to a higher dimention array, the following is a simple example:

```
aArray=np.array([1,1,1])

bArray=np.array([2,2,2])

aList=[aArray, bArray]

xArray=np.array(aList)
```

xArray's shape is (2,3), it's a standard np array. This operation avoids a loop programming.

Answer (score 3):

just use following code

```
c = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]])
```

Then it will give you

you can check shape and dimension of matrix by using following code

c.shape

c.ndim

Answer (score 2):

I am using large data sets exported to a python file in the form

```
XVals1 = [.........] 
XVals2 = [.........]
```

Each list is of identical length.  I use

```
>>> a1 = np.array(SV.XVals1)

>>> a2 = np.array(SV.XVals2)
```

Then

```
>>> A = np.matrix([a1,a2])
```

Comment: What is 'SV' here