# convert a 2D numpy array to a 2D numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a python code in which I have to convert a 2D array to a 2D matrix so that I can use it to calculate inverse.For that I am using numpy.matrix(array) but it is not working. Can anyone tell how to convert a 2D array to a numpy matrix? The array consists of all float numbers

Comment: Inverse of [Numpy matrix to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array)

Comment: You can also call `np.linalg.inv` on the array directly.

Answer (score 29):

If `a` is your array, [`np.asmatrix(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html) is a matrix.

Comment: error
File "C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev\123.py", line 47, in <module>
print A.I
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 859, in getI
return asmatrix(func(self))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1574, in pinv
u, s, vt = svd(a, 0)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1278,in svd
a =_fastCopyAndTranspose(t, a)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 145, in _fastCopyAndTranspose
cast_arrays = cast_arrays + (_fastCT(a.astype(type))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @abcdxx Come on, you can't just bomb me with a bunch of error messages, especially not without context. _What_ gives you this error, what parameters did you pass to which function etc?

Comment: I hv a 2D list I converted it to array using np.array and then further calculated inverse from matrix using A.I where A=np.asmatrix(array) but it gave the above error

Comment: Why don't you convert that list directly into a matrix? Anyway, you probably should post a minimum working example in a new question about this error, if you can't find it via google.

Comment: So you got an answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17449883/321973), and as you can see `.asmatrix` was used

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of lists (as you mentioned), you need to convert it first to a numpy array; see [how to convert 2d list to 2d numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7717380/2062965)

A short example is given here:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[  0. +0.j,   1.j,   2. -2.j],
     [  4. -4.j,   5. -5.j,   6. -1.j],
     [  8. -8.j,   9. -9.j,  10.]]
b = np.matrix(np.array(a))
b_inv = np.linalg.inv(b)
```