# to convert a list to a 2D matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
arr2=[0]*(x^2) # x is the length of the list data
for i in range(x):
    arr2[i]=data[i].split(',')#data is a list like:['1,2','3,4']
arr2=np.array(arr2)
A=np.asmatrix(arr2)
print A.I
```

This is giving error as setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: Please give some context about what you're trying to do and give a specific question related to the problem you're having.

Comment: I need to have a matrix to take out its inverse

Comment: @abcdxx did you check my answer?

Comment: @abcdxx You don't need to create the intermediate array to create the matrix, check the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> data = ['1,2','3,4']
>>> arr2=[ map(float,x.split(',')) for x in data]
>>> arr2 = np.asarray(arr2)
>>> A = np.asmatrix(arr2)
>>> A.I
matrix([[-2. ,  1. ],
        [ 1.5, -0.5]])
```