# list comprehension replace for loop in 2D matrix

Tags: python, int, output, list-comprehension

I try to use list comprehension to replace the for loop.

original file is

```
2 3 4 5 6 3
1 2 2 4 5 5
1 2 2 2 2 4
```

for loop

```
line_number = 0
for line in file:
    line_data = line.split()
    Cordi[line_number, :5] = line_data 
    line_number += 1
```

output is

```
[[2 3 4 5 6 3]
 [1 2 2 4 5 5]
 [1 2 2 2 2 4]]
```

if use list comprehension instead, for what I can think of is (I have to change the data type to int, so it can be plotted in later part of the program)

```
Cordi1= [int(x) for x in line.split() for line in data]
```

but the output is

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

but `line.split() for line in data` is actually a list, and if I try

```
Cordi1 = [int(x) for x in name of the list]
```

it works, why this happens?

Comment: You can produce a list with a list comprehension, but `Cordi` is a numpy array instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ah, so I cannot produce a 2D array with list comprehension?

Comment: You could convert the nested lists to a 2D array afterwards, but there could well be better options for producing a numpy array from this data.

Comment: See [how to convert 2d list to 2d numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7717380) for a conversion option.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you, ah, but actually either a nested 2D list or a numpy 2D list, they work well plotted. But in future applications, that may cause problems. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have the order of your loops swapped; they should be ordered in the same way they would be nested, from left to right:

```
[int(x) for line in data for x in line.split()]
```

This loops over `data` first, then for each `line` iteration, iterates over `line.split()` to produce `x`. You then produce one *flat* list of integers from these.

However, since you are trying to build a list of lists, you need to nest a list comprehension inside another:

```
Cordi1 = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in data]
```

Demo:

```
>>> data = '''\
... 2 3 4 5 6 3
... 1 2 2 4 5 5
... 1 2 2 2 2 4
... '''.splitlines()
>>> [int(x) for line in data for x in line.split()]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]
>>> [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in data]
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3], [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]]
```

If you wanted a multidimensional numpy array from this, you can either convert the above directly to an array or create an array from the data then reshape:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in data])
array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3],
       [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]])
>>> np.array([int(i) for line in data for i in line.split()]).reshape((3, 6))
array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3],
       [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]])
```